# How to disable or supress request 'No Disk in the drive'?

Tags: c++, crt

When I try to change current disk using _chdrive (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0d1409hb.aspx) to check what drives are connected to PC, _chdrive call shows request "There is no disk in the drive. Cancel/Retry/Continue", like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpoC7.png]

This request shows only for removable drives that registered at system and hidden because they have no connected devices, like empty card-reader. But I just want to receive 0 in case drive connected and switching to him was successfull, and "not 0" otherwise.

In addition, I have to use Сrt functions, I must not use WinAPI directly.
Is that possible to supress or disable that request at runtime, without changing global system settings like registry modifications etc.?

Also i tried to use _access with mode 0 (checks existence only) instead of _chdrive to check is drives roots like "C:\", "D:\" existed or not, but it leads to the same result.

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Perhaps the [_getdrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdhk0xd2.aspx) function is what you're looking for.

Comment: @RetiredNinja not at all. It returns all registered drives, including not connected. For example, my card-reader has 4 ports, they registered as drives H, I, J, K, and _getdrives always returns them as '1' bit, even if nothing connected to appropriate ports. Therefore I must check is drive connected or not. I try to check existence of drive's root, like _access("H:\\",0), and at this point OS shows request "No disk in the drive", exactly the same as when I call _chdrive.